# Import cucumber test result with XRay API using Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, cucumber, jira-xray

I'm trying to perform an import of a cucumber test with the Xray API on Python, to be more specific I'm trying to translate this curl on Python side (it's a multipart form) :

```
curl -u usr:pass -F info=@$xrayResultFilePath -F result=@$pathToCucumberJson $jiraUrl/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber/multipart
```

I tried in many different ways the python code I'm stucked on looks something like this:

```
response = requests.post(
    atc_xray_url,
    auth=(creds.username, creds.password),
    files={"info": open("cucumber.result.json", "rb"),
            "result": open("xray_result.json", "rb")},
)
response.raise_for_status()
```

I also tried to change the tags, to add them in a tuple like I found on the internet, solutions found here, but no result everytime I get this error:

```
<status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri:
```

The curl is working, but the Python code is not. I could use the subprocess library but this shoud be a multiplatform solution so if this could be done with a thing in Python, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

[This repository](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets) that I made available some time ago provides several code snippets, including [one](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/import_automation_results/python/import_results_cucumber_multipart.py) precisely for that use case.
Your code is similar to the following one though; you may use basic auth or personal auth tokens, if you have a Jira DC version >= 8.14.
Given the result code you obtain, the problem may be on the URL that you use, which is not clear whether it's the same or not that you have on your curl. Note that you can also use v2 of the endpoint, as I show ahead.

```
import requests
import json

jira_base_url = "http://192.168.56.102"
jira_username = "admin"
jira_password = "admin"
personal_access_token = "OTE0ODc2NDE2NTgxOnrhigwOreFoyNIA9lXTZaOcgbNY"

...

files = {
        'result': ('cucumber.json', open(r'cucumber.json', 'rb')),
        'info': ('info.json', json.dumps(info_json) )
        }

# importing results using HTTP basic authentication
# response = requests.post(f'{jira_base_url}/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/cucumber/multipart', params=params, files=files, auth=(jira_username, jira_password))

# importing results using Personal Access Tokens 
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + personal_access_token}
response = requests.post(f'{jira_base_url}/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/cucumber/multipart', files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately still getting the same error even by changing the version, but i can see that I have version 8.13.15 of Jira

Comment: Have you doublechecked the URL you are using?  Which version of python and the requests library are you using?

Comment: Yes double checked, python version is 3.7, requests 2.22

Comment: I've prepared a Dockerfile and a working code example for you. I've specified those versions you mentioned. Hope it helps, if so I will update the answer above the full code snippet. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d4d40fbeff717ffa1716a2b535f86c1820220307103242/ce6983